# why the low poly 3d model became round blender

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender and I tried to create a low poly elephant, but something went wrong and all the sharp edges became round.

Someone knows what happened and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: You probably added a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, just remove it.

Comment: Are you using any modifiers on this model?